# INNER JOIN en C# "Incorrect sintax near the keyword 'INNER'

Tags: c#, sql-server

Como ejecutar correctamente una consulta INNER JOIN, siempre que intento ejecutarlo me detecta o el INNER o una a

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'a'.'

```
string query = "SELECT CodigoArticulo,Titulo,UnidadesDeBodega,UnidadesDeCompra,UnidadesDeVenta,b.Descripcion,c.DESCRIPCION" +
                "FROM CatalogoArticulos a INNER JOIN CATALOGO_FAMILIAS b ON a.Familia = b.CodigoFamilia INNER JOIN CATALOGO_FESTEJOS c" +
                "ON a.Festejo = c.ID WHERE a.CodigoArticulo=@CodigoArticulo";
```

o si hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo seria bastante ayuda

Comment: Me parece que tienes un error de sintaxis, por que entre `DESCRIPCION` y `FROM` no tienes un espacio en blanco, entonces te lo esta leyendo así: `DESCRIPCIONFROM` lo cual daría error de sintaxis, entonces o dejas un espacio después de la descripción o dejas un espacio antes del `FROM`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string query = "SELECT CodigoArticulo,Titulo,UnidadesDeBodega,UnidadesDeCompra,UnidadesDeVenta,b.Descripcion,c.DESCRIPCION " +
                "FROM CatalogoArticulos a INNER JOIN CATALOGO_FAMILIAS b ON a.Familia = b.CodigoFamilia INNER JOIN CATALOGO_FESTEJOS c " +
                "ON a.Festejo = c.ID WHERE a.CodigoArticulo=@CodigoArticulo";
```

Es casi el mismo código, le puse los espacios necesarios para que la query se ejecute adecuadamente.

Comment: ¿Y cuál era el fallo?

Comment: Antes de los signos `+`, el texto no tiene espacio, cosa que en la siguiente línea se concatena generando código ajeno a SQL, y por lo tanto, lance errores de sintaxis